# Return result set from SQL Server stored procedure to vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

The following stored procedure works as I want in the Visual Studio designer. The result is a table containing all the race distances for the input  `@CourseName`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCourseDistancesProc]
    @CourseName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT
        RaceDistances.RaceDistance
    FROM  
        RacingMaster
    JOIN
        RaceDistances ON RacingMaster.Dist_Of_Race_FK = RaceDistances.PKRaceDistancesId
    JOIN
        Courses ON RacingMaster.RM_Course_FK = Courses.PKCourseId
    WHERE
        CourseName = @CourseName
END
```

I want to call the stored procedure from a vb.net application. What data type do I declare as the output variable so that the full result set is returned to the calling app?

Comment: Output variables are for returning a single value. In SQL Server you can return the results just by using the select statement

Comment: @JamesZ  I am not sure I understand. In my example what would I select?

Comment: Just as it is now, is there a problem / error with it?

Comment: I call the proc from the vb.net app thus:   Set retval = cmd.Execute . However I cannot find anything coming back that matches the results produced by the proc when run in the designer.

Comment: The return value is used for error handling, it's not the data: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was obviously more work to be done than I had realized, but just in case anyone else stumbles across this question the solution I finally adapted from elsewhere is:-

```vb
Dim myConn As SqlConnection
Dim myCmd As SqlCommand
Dim results As String
Dim ConnectionString As String

' Create the connection string.
ConnectionString = "Data Source=*********;" & _
                    "Initial Catalog=*******;" & _
                    "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
myConn = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

myConn.Open()
Dim InputName As String
InputName = TextBox1.Text

myCmd = New SqlCommand()
myCmd.CommandText = "getCourseDistancesProc"
myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName", Odbc.OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = InputName
myCmd.Connection = myConn
Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

If myReader.HasRows Then

    Do While myReader.Read()
        Dim var As String
        var = myReader.GetString(0)
        MsgBox(var)
    Loop
Else
        MsgBox("No rows found.")
End If

myReader.Close()
```

Obviously, the above is just to demonstrate that the requested data is indeed coming back from the database. But now I know that it is I can handle it in a more useful way.

Comment: This is not answer or solution. This just exposes that you simply didn't research what to do. In reality you had no issue.

Comment: @T S Well, in the spirit of this site, rather than commenting on what is not the answer would it not be better to provide an answer? That is why I posed the question after all.

Comment: Well, in the spirit of this site, your question needs to be "well-researched" . In your case, there was no issue but rather lack of knowledge/experience. You could find hundreds of examples, **"how to retrieve a recordset from stored procedure"** by simply googling it.